# Union in C++ used in the context of Bison

Tags: c++, bison

Referring to this [blog post](http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/4/)

There is a union defined as below:

```
%union {
    Node *node;
    NBlock *block;
    NExpression *expr;
    NStatement *stmt;
    NIdentifier *ident;
    NVariableDeclaration *var_decl;
    std::vector<NVariableDeclaration*> *varvec;
    std::vector<NExpression*> *exprvec;
    std::string *string;
    int token;
}
```

My question is: How could this union be used when it is **anonymous** and how was it actually used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse bison's `%union` directive with the C/C++ syntax.

In the code generated by bison, there will be a C/C++ `union`, whose body is copied from the `%union` directive, but it is certainly not anonymous: its name is `YYSTYPE`. However, you hardly ever need to know that, since the only exposed variable with that type is `yylval`. (The internal bison stack is also composed of elements of type `YYSTYPE` but it is not exposed to user code.)

There are various other possible ways to define `YYSTYPE`, as described by the bison manual. For example, you can create your own C/C++ `union` (or `struct`) type, as described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Structured-Value-Type). However, these advanced `bison` features are rarely required.